# How can I create, and consume a pseudo-random password?

Tags: passwords, forgot-password, password-recovery

I have an Android app that I allow users to have a password in and "lock" the app so their friends can't look inside without their password. It doesn't use a web service or anything, and the password is stored in a private file within the app. Problem is, the users like to forget their password, then email me asking me to do something about it. Right now I can't. So what I want to do is have something that creates, and consumes a random password. The user could email me, and I could give them some random key the app could recognize, and let them in so they can change their password.

It doesn't have to be anything super secure. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its a good idea to implement a "backdoor" in your application. THis will create a very bad taste.

If i understood correctly, you want to "unlock" the application, not knowing if the user doing this is in some way authorized. I steal a device, send you an email and you take care i can see the data. Sounds bad...

All (good) safes i know rely on the user to take care of their keys. They want security and they are responsible.

EDIT

You can provide a "security question".

Anything else i tried to construct for an "autonomous" password reset raises sever security questions (what are the authentication/authorization mechanics)

EDIT

How far are you willing to go? Assuring the possession of something (like an SMS or mail account) may reduce the issues and give some impression of security. So you can intercept SMS or mail from a PREDEFINED (application settings) account with lets say the key word "unlock". If not set, this feature is disabled. SMS interception should no be that hard.

Comment: Yes, I know, I know... but the data they have in the app really isn't that sensitive. It's not anything that could get their identity stolen or anything, and they tend to get really pissed when they lock themselves out and I have to tell them they need to reinstall the app.

Comment: @Scienceprodigy if it's not valuable enough to require a secure password, why have a password at all?

Comment: I think it's more of an annoyance than it is a security issue for them, if somebody sees their data.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Something could be worth putting a lock on the door, but not worth having an alarm system. Something could be worth having an alarm system, but not worth having armed guards. Etc.

Comment: @Jay the question is not about whether to lock the door, but whether to lock the door then provide a man-sized catflap so anyone can walk through it. If it's worth locking the door, then lock it. If it's decided to allow anyone access, then requiring the users to remember a password makes it harder for them to use the system and gives a false sense of security.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Sure, I've used security systems that amount to, "You're not allowed in, unless you tell me that you should be allowed in, in which case we let you in with no further questions." If you have a backdoor that's so easy to use that anybody can get in without your password, then sure, you've made security worthless. But one can certainly think of security systems that would not be adequate to protect nuclear missile launch codes but would be good enough to protect lesser secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just build password reset functionality in the app itself?  If it's not using a web service, why do you or your server need to be involved at all?

If they don't remember their security passwords, for example, your server could store an md5 hash of their password to match up their mobile device with their record on your server so you can send them a key to reset the app.

Comment: What about having the security question concept in the app itself?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thoughts:

Is there any sort of registration process? If so, at registration time you could randomly generate  a second password that you don't tell the user but just keep on file for such contingencies. Or similarly, you could offer users a "password recovery" option -- click this button to generate a backdoor password.

You could have some algorithm that generates a password from the machine id of the device and that works as an alternate password. If you were a big organization with millions of copies of your app out there, or if the information in your app was super secret, this would be a super bad idea, as sooner or later hackers would figure out the algorithm and then they could break into any machine they wanted to. But if you're a small target, it's likely no one would work hard enough to crack it.

Do you necessarily know anything about your users? Like could you generate a password from their credit card number or their address or some such? Of course this makes you vulnerable to any hacker who could discover whatever information about a potential target.

Anything like this you do you are going to create a big potential security hole: What if someone steals someone else's device, then emails you and says they lost their password? How do you know it's the rightful owner of the data? If anybody can call or email and say, Hey, I lost my password, please let me in the back door, then you have no security any more.